# I have PDF templates where PDF will be generated out after the user submitted few form values in JSP

Tags: java

I have a requirement in the Java web application to generate the PDFs from the template. The user will enter the values in jsp and then PDF will be generated using the template. Please advise where i keep the templates

1. Read from the DB.
2. Read from the file system.
3. Read from the DB/File System and load in the web Application context.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Im confused... what is the question?

Comment: we use xslt templates in our applications

Comment: It depends:  How static are the templates?  How quick do changes to the templates need to be enacted?  Are you planning to put in place some user GUI to manipulate the templates, like with a web form, or are the developers maintaining them?

Comment: The template means predesigned PDF Pages. The user values are populated in the template PDF and inserted into DB. The template hardly have some changes. The templates are packaged as the part of EAR file.